# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos 3n \left( \exp\left( \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[3]{n} \ln(n+1)} \right) - 1 \right)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos 3n \left( \exp\left( \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[3]{n} \ln(n+1)} \right) - 1 \right)$ absolutely and conditionally converges?

The only idea I have is to use Taylor expansion but the $\cos 3n$ multiplier spoils everything,

Comment: Not rigorous but remember that $ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{x}-1}{x} \to 1 $
We can use it with $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\cos3n\left(\exp\left(\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt[3]{n}\ln(n+1)}\right)-1\right)=\frac{\cos\left(3n\right)\left(\exp\left(\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt[3]{n}\ln(n+1)}\right)-1\right)\cdot\left(\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt[3]{n}\ln(n+1)}\right)}{\left(\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt[3]{n}\ln(n+1)}\right)}\approx\frac{\cos\left(3n\right)\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\sqrt[3]{n}\ln\left(1+n\right)} $$
I think all that is left to prove now is that $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos (3n) (-1)^n $ is bounded for Dirichlet test now